# synchronize 2 method with another method but not with each other

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

I have `methodA` and `methodB` and `methodSync` in my java program.
I want that when a thread is inside `methodSync` other threads don't run the `methodA` and `methodB` and wait for `methodSync` to end. But `methodA` and `methodB` can run simultaneously.

If I want to sync 3 methods with each other I can use this code:

```
private static final Object LOCK = new Object();

public static void methodA() {
        synchronized (LOCK) {
                //Do Job
        }
}

public static void methodB() {
        synchronized (LOCK) {
                //Do Job
        }
}

public static void methodSync() {
        synchronized (LOCK) {
                //Do Job
        }
}
```

But this is not a solution for me because I want to run `methodA` and `methodB` simultaneously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private static final Object A = new Object();
private static final Object B = new Object();

public static void methodA() {
    synchronized (A) {
            //Do Job
    }
}

public static void methodB() {
    synchronized (B) {
            //Do Job
    }
}

public static void methodSync() {
    synchronized (A) {
      synchronized (B) {
            //Do Job
      }
    }
}
```

I guess that will work.  Good luck.

P.S. You can replace synchronized with ReadWriteLock (acquiring the read lock in methods A & B and the write lock in methodSync.  If that's worth doing is if you want two callers in methodA at the same time.